# How can i validate the response i receive from browser logs?

Tags: java, selenium, logging

I'm trying to get logs from the browser while running my test with selenium webdriver.

```
driver.manage().logs().get("browser").forEach(l -> System.out.println(l));
```

I want to print a message to the console if i get "severe" error.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround to your problem...

```
LogEntries logEntries = driver.manage().logs().get(LogType.BROWSER);
for (LogEntry entry : logEntries) {
      System.out.println(new Date(entry.getTimestamp()) + " " + entry.getLevel() + " " + entry.getMessage());
}
```

If this doesn't work, put a lag `Thread.sleep(1000)` before getting logs like below

```
Thread.sleep(1000);
LogEntries logEntries = driver.manage().logs().get(LogType.BROWSER);
for (LogEntry entry : logEntries) {
    System.out.println(new Date(entry.getTimestamp()) + " " + entry.getLevel() + " " + entry.getMessage());
}
```